# How to sent settings of diagram(design) in RedHat devStudio to another developer

Tags: jboss, redhat, soa, diagram, jboss-developer-studio

I have JBoss developer studio and plugin for SOA development. So I can look at switchyard.xml like diagram (in devstudio it named like "Design"). The studio generates this diagram not at good way. So I have to spent 30 minutes to make it readble. The question is: How to sent the Diagram settings (Arrangement of elements) to another developer with same project? (picture from intenet) [this it is look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y0bwg.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

the SwitchYard editor uses the Graphiti framework under the covers, which relies on a hidden ".xml" directory to stash the actual diagram layout. To share this part of the project you will need to "un-hide" the directory and include it in the project zip or check it into github.

For example, in the Project Explorer, look for the down-pointing triangle in the view toolbar and select "Filters and Customization..." Turn off the ".* resources" filter and you should see the ".xml" folder appear (as well as ".settings" and a few other things).

With it visible, it should appear in the Export->Archive File wizard for you to include it in a project you share with another developer. Or check it into git as part of the project and that should work as well.